# Jar file (Project) in Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, executable-jar

I have a jar file whose contents (multiple class files) I am presently viewing via a decompiler (jd-gui).  However I need to run through code from few other jars and its very difficult and inefficient to do so with a decompiler. Is there a way I can import this jar onto eclipse as a project?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse, there's a jd plugin (http://jd.benow.ca/), you just import the jar as a library in your project and browse the code from there.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tried out your suggestion. Will mark it as answer if it works out for me.